# Error en gráfica

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Cordial saludo. Tengo el siguiente problema al momento de cargar una grafica, debo graficar por cada comuna la catidad de alumnos, despues de haber seleccionado el grado, el problema que se presente es que las barras cargan todas del mismo tamaño como si no estubiera contando la cantidad por cada comuna al hacer un `cosole.log(response)`, me doy cuenta que solo esta trayendo un valor en el arreglo y lo esta repitiendo en cada posición por tal motivo cada barra sale del mismo tamaño, la consulta que tengo a la tabla esta bien pero no se donde agregar las demas consultas para hacer una por cada comuna ya que son 7 de estas.

Este es el codigo `index.php` que muestra la grafica luego de seleccionar el grado.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Estadistica</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartJS/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .caja{
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
        }
        .caja select{
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .resultados{
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            width: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
    <body> 
        <div class="caja">
            <select onChange="mostrarResultados(this.value);">
                <?php
                    for($i=701;$i<1109;$i++){
                        if($i == 701){
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="resultados"><canvas id="grafico"></canvas></div>
    </body>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(mostrarResultados(2015));  
                function mostrarResultados(year){
                    $('.resultados').html('<canvas id="grafico"></canvas>');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'php/procesar.php',
                        data: 'year='+year,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success:function(response){

                            console.log(response);

                            var Datos = {
                                    labels : ['Comuna 1', 'Comuna 2', 'Comuna 3', 'Comuna 4', 'Comuna 5', 'Comuna 6', 'Comuna 7', 'Nulos'],
                                    datasets : [
                                        {
                                            fillColor : 'rgba(91,228,146,0.6)', //COLOR DE LAS BARRAS
                                            strokeColor : 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)', //COLOR DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightFill : 'rgba(73,206,180,0.6)', //COLOR "HOVER" DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightStroke : 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)', //COLOR "HOVER" DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            data : response
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            var contexto = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
                            window.Barra = new Chart(contexto).Bar(Datos, { responsive : true });
                            Barra.clear();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
    </script>
</html>
```

Este es el código de la consulta procesar.php

```
<?php
    include_once('conexion.php');
    class Procesar extends Model{

        public function __construct(){ 
            parent::__construct(); 
        }

        public function build_report($year){
            $total = array();
            for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
                $month = $i+1;
                $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS total FROM tbl_consulta1 WHERE comuna = 'UNO' OR grado = '$year'");    
                $total[$i] = 0;
                foreach ($sql as $key){ 
                    $total[$i] = ($key['total'] == null)? 0 : $key['total']; }
            }            
            return $total;
        }

    }

    if($_POST['year']){
        $class = new Procesar;
        $run = $class->build_report($_POST['year']);
        exit(json_encode($run));
    }
?>
```

Esta es un pantallazo del error por consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me parece que tu error esta en el foreach
Tienes:

```
$total[$i] = 0;
```

Osea que en dentro del foreach estas asignando en el campo 0 el mismo valor siempre.

```
foreach ($sql as $key){ 
    $total["""$i vale 0 en este momento"""] = ($key['total'] == null)? 0 : $key['total'];
}
```

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente

```
foreach ($sql as $key){ 
    $total[] = ($key['total'] == null)? 0 : $key['total']; 
}
```

Quitando la variable $i dentro del arreglo, asignara cada uno de esos valores en una posición diferente del arreglo `$total[]`.

Espero te sirva la respuesta

Comment: Hola he realizado los cambio que me sugeriste y obviamente surgieron cambios,

Comment: Hola he realizado los cambio que me sugeriste y obviamente surgieron cambios, pero no me muestra valores reales, esta cargando lo siguiente, {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 4, 6: 0, 7: 6, 8: 0}
1: 0
2: 0
3: 2
4: 0
5: 4
6: 0
7: 6
8: 0

Comment: Puedes colocar una foto de lo que te retorna la ejecucion de ese query, pero directamente en la base de datos?

Comment: Esta consulta directamente en la base de datos me devuelve un una campo con valor NULL, obviamente reemplazando el valor de grado por un grado de la BD

Comment: Entonces, según lo que me acabas de decir, la consulta a la base de datos esta mal.

Comment: No se como abordar este error, tengo esta otra consulta que si me devuelve los valores desde la bd, está consulta me devuelve grado y cantidad por cada comuna pero no se como plasmarla en el php: SELECT grado, COUNT(id_alumno) AS cantidad, tbl_comunas.comuna AS comuna
FROM tbl_alumnos LEFT JOIN tbl_comunas
ON tbl_alumnos.comuna = tbl_comunas.comuna
WHERE grado ='701'
GROUP BY tbl_comunas.comuna